# Как создать цикл товаров Woocommerce+Simple Auction при разработке плагина?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть связка: WooCommerce + Woocommerce Simple Auctions.
Необходимо в теле мною созданного плагина перебрать товары, выбрать только те, которые являются аукционами и изменить нужные значения аукциона без вывода на фронт-енд.

Проблема в том, что когда я использую стандартный цикл по товарам, то он не содержит необходимые свойства и мета-поля, которые относятся к аукциону. Т.е. они принадлежат к классу WC_Product_Simple а должны принадлежать WC_Product_Auction
Возникла мысль, что я просто цепляю свой цикл не на тот хук.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю, хук тут ни при чем. Вы используете достаточно поздний: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference Обычно все инициализации проходят по init. Плагин аукционов платный, установить для изучения не получится. Судя по скриншотам на Envato, аукционы - это товары, да (было изначально сомнение в этом). Но, скорее всего, они скрыты при выводе в цикле путем изменения цикла WC. Попробуйте добавить в параметры вашего запроса `'suppress_filters' => true` https://wp-kama.ru/hook/posts_where

Comment: @KAGGDesign Нет, к сожалению, это не сработало. В коде плагина нашел, что класс WC_Product_Auction наследует от WC_Product. Подскажите, может в каком направлении копать?  использовал этот код https://pastebin.com/fV33s8Gr для вывода кнопок ставок на товаре, так вот когда там вывожу print_r($product) - все ок, имеется доступ к нужным свойствам и WC_Product_Auction Object.

Comment: Выведите в коде на вашей картинке просто print_r( $product ); и посмотрите, что получится. А вообще-то тяжело гадать, не видя кода плагина.

Comment: @KAGGDesign оно выводит WC_Product_Simple Object. Плагин можно найти в свободном доступе, например тут https://www.downloadfreethemes.cc/woocommerce-simple-auctions-v1-2-20/ Буду невероятно признателен за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я и предполагал с самого начала, плагин аукционов производит фильтрацию запроса WP_Query. В файле `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-simple-auctions/woocommerce-simple-auctions.php` есть функция `pre_get_posts()` которая подавляет вывод аукционов. Покопавшись в коде, я нашёл, что если установлен параметр запроса `'auction_arhive' => true,`, то плагин аукционов отключает свои фильтры.

Вот снимок экрана отладчика, на котором видно, что текущий объект в цикле имееет класс `WC_Product_Auction`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в запрос добавить параметр `'product_type' => 'auction',`, то в выборку из базы попадут только товары-аукционы. Рабочий код такой:

```
function sample_func() {
    global $post;

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
        'auction_arhive' => true,
        'product_type'   => 'auction',
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();
        $id = $post->ID;
        $item = wc_get_product( $id );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'sample_func' );
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо! Вы очень выручили и помогли!